# Reading ints in input in a Python program

Tags: python, input, integer

I have to take input from the user then the operator has to print what number is before the input and after the input like:

input= 3
has to print 2 and 4

I used range, did I do it wrong? I am just a beginner in Python.

```
number=int(input)

for num in range(number ,+ 1, -1):
    print(num)
```

Comment: You don't need a for loop, you don't need a range.  You need `print(number-1)` and `print(number+1)`.

Comment: You didn't call the input function and as @TimRoberts said no need to use the range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to use `input()` to let the user register a number.

Then, simply print the number with `number - 1` and `number + 1`.

```py
number = int(input("What is your number? "))
print(f"{number - 1} {number + 1}")
```

Outputs to:

```bash
What is your number? 3
2 4
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need range do this task

```
num = int(input())

print(num-1, num+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers which say that you don't require a loop are perfectly fine, however I want to add a little suggestion in case you need to print more than just the number before and after. Maybe (as your first implementation suggests) you want to print the 5 numbers before and after. In this case you can do:

```
R = 5 #range
N = int(input("Enter your number. "))

numbers = [ i for i in range(N-R,N+R+1) if i != N]

print(numbers)
```